# Is that possible that using stack pointer to locate/index local variables on stack with llvm?

Tags: stack, llvm, stack-pointer

I'm trying to modify llvm X86 backend to use rsp to locate/index local variables rather than rbp. The problem is that the offset between local variables and rsp is not fixed, so I have to calculate it by myself. 
It's easy to handle it if rsp's location was modified by these instructions as follows:

```
push 
pop
sub rsp, $immediate
```

In these situations, I can know the offset at compile-time. 
But nowadays I get stuck in a problem. I find that rsp is not only modified by these instructions mentioned before. For example:

```
lstr = (char *)alloca(strlen(ss) + 1);
```

This instruction will modify rsp like this and I can't know the offset at compile-time.

```
sub rsp, $register
```

Is it possible or not to use llvm to generate execute file which using stack pointer to locate local variables?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no. There are many cases when stack pointer value may change in "non-constant way". Examples include VLAs (either direct or via alloca() calls), variadic functions, etc. Also note that in some cases the stack could be realigned dynamically as well.